# How can I "bind" two speaker outputs in OSX? (the feature is gone)

Tags: macos, audio, macbook-pro, thunderbolt-display

I used to be able to make music play out both my laptop speakers and also my monitor speakers.

I did this in the System Preferences and "creating" a new audio device that composed of both my laptop and my monitor.  However sometime later I'm unable to find or locate the setting to create a new audio device that allows for this.

How do I re-enable sound out both my laptop and monitor speakers?

The only changes I made since I did this include: Install Logix, Install (and remove) Boom audio boost, and normal system updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try multi-output devices in `/Applications/Utilities/Audio Midi Setup.app`?

[image]

Comment: Please rate the answer up if it meets your requirement.